Flutter localization override
I have my custom library which has own localization. Then in my main app i would like to override some translations in my custom library. For example:
CustomLibrary has this translation in en.arb:
{
    "genericEmail": "E-mail",
}

In my main app i have same key but different translation:
{
    "genericEmail": "Your email",
}

My custom library has a Widget which use the translation
class EmailWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const EmailWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final translate = CustomLibraryLocalizations.of(context);
    return Text(translate.genericEmail);
  }
}

I use EmailWidgetin my main app and i would like my main app translation replace my custom librarytranslation
I've even tried to put my Main app localizationsDelegatesfirst but did not work
    return MaterialApp(
      locale: const Locale("en"),
      localizationsDelegates: const [
        ...AppLocalizations.localizationsDelegates,
        CustomLibraryLocalizations.delegate
      ],
      supportedLocales: const <Locale>[
        ...AppLocalizations.supportedLocales,
        ...CustomLibraryLocalizations.supportedLocales,
      ],
    );

